# How to pass my stack items inside a function?

Tags: python

I created a program in Python, which returns a boolean True value if the number of `a` and `b` elements are equal, and False if otherwise. Every time I run this, I get a "True" output instead of "False". Can somebody figure out the problem with my code?

```
def equal(s):
    s = Stack()
    stack_a = Stack()
    stack_b = Stack()
    while not s.is_empty():
        if s.top() == 'a':
            var = s.pop()
            push(stack_a, var)
        else:
            var = s.pop()
            push(stack_b, var)
    if stack_a.size() == stack_b.size():
        return True
    else:
        return False 

my_list = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
print equal(my_list)
```

Comment: PEP8 is your friend: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Comment: What on earth is a `Stack`?

Comment: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: Well `my_list` is clearly a `list`, as per what's in the code :) Not sure about `Stack`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `Stack` class is some valid implementation of the stack container, it seems that you are creating an **empty** stack

```
S = Stack()
```

Probably you wanted to use something like

```
S = Stack(S)
```

So checking whether there are the same amount of 'a's and 'b's in it always return True (as `StackA.size() == 0` and `StackB.size() == 0`)

Also, the much easier approach would be to do

```
def equal(S):
    return len( [x for x in S if x=='a'] ) == len( [x for x in S if x=='b'] )
```

or (as suggested by Erik Allik)

```
def equal(S):
    return sum( 1 for x in S if x=='a' ) == sum( 1 for x in S if x=='b' )
```

Comment: `return sum(1 for x in S if x == 'a') == ...` would be slightly more efficient also :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `equal` function takes a parameter named `S`, but then right at the beginning of the funciton, you are overriding the contents of `S` that were passed into the function with a newly created empty stack: `S = Stack()`, so just remove that line and you have one less bug.

Also, I think it's fair to suggest that your `push()` function, wherever you've defined it, should really be a method of the `Stack` class; otherwise it doesn't really make sense to define stacks as a class but not put all tightly stack related operations into that class in the form of methods.

Comment: Interestingly, for most languages with OOP features (Python included), `X.methodA(...)` is more or less syntactic sugar for `methodA(X, ...)`. But yes it is better to actually make these methods, otherwise the class is brittle and useless.

Comment: It's not only about the syntactic sugar; it's about polymorphism/dynamic (single, in Python's case) dispatch—functions don't have that (unless with a special decorator); OO code does. Also, it's about readability: if OO is available but is not used, the reader is left puzzled with "was there a particular reason to not make it a method?".

Answer (score 0):

As well as the problem with

```
S = Stack()
```

overriding the stack to get a length of 0, once fixed you'll get a crash because you're using:

```
var = s.pop()
```

instead of

```
var = S.pop()
```

Note that the fast way of doing this is

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(S)
return counts['a'] == counts['b']
```